# Limit and display the child rows of each category (in a single table) to a specific number - laravel

Tags: laravel

I've 2 models with name Product and ProductType as shown below. Here ProductType is category which has many products. I want to display first product (only one product) from each category. How can I do it?

I tried to use limit but it shows product in ascending order henceforth showing 2 products from 1st product type.

Model: ProductType

```
public function products1()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'product_type','id');
}
```

Database: product_types

```
id  name

1   ABC
2   DEF
```

Database: products

```
id  product_type     name

1       1            product1
2       1            product2
3       1            product3
4       2            product4
5       2            product5
6       2            product6
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $ptype1 = ProductType::with(['products1'=> function($query) {
            return $query->limit(2);
        }])->get();
return view('frontend.index', compact('ptype'));
}
```

result I got from above controller:

ptype: [{"id": 1, "name": "ABC", products1: [{"id": 1, "product_type": 1, "name": "product1"}, {"id": 2, "product_type": 1, "name": "product2"}]}, {"id": 2, "name": "DEF", products1: []} ]

Expected result:

ptype: [{"id": 1, "name": "ABC", products1: [{"id": 1, "product_type": 1, "name": "product1"}]}, {"id": 2, "name": "DEF", products1: [{"id": 3, "product_type": 2, "name": "product3"}]} ]

**Edit:**
I need 2 row per category. For simplicity, I mentioned 1 row per category in above question but it seems everybody is confused. How to get 2 rows of products per product_type category?

I tried to use groupBy as suggested by A.A Noman in the comment but it gives one row per category only. How can I get 2 row in each category?

**New code**

```
public function index()
{
    $ptype1 = ProductType::with(['products1'=> function($query) {
            return $query->groupBy('product_type');
        }])->get();
return view('frontend.index', compact('ptype'));
}
```

Comment: use group by method in query

Comment: add limit in relation

Comment: @A.ANoman groupBy gave 1 row per category. How can I get 2 rows per category? I've included the new code in the above question. Please have a look.

Comment: @AmritaStha, I tried your query many times and many ways what you want. But I can't get your required query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate relation to get the latest product for each product type
In model

```
public function latest_product(){
    return $this->hasOne(Product::class,'product_type','id')->latest();
}
```

In controller

```
public function index(){
    $ptype1 = ProductType::with('latest_product')->get();
    return view('frontend.index', compact('ptype'));
}
```

Comment: Sorry I mentioned single row from each product_type (category) for simplicity. What if I need 3 rows of each product_type ?

Answer (score 0):

why not using first() or latest()  methods;

```
$ptype1 = ProductType::with(['products1'=> function($query) {
            return $query->first();
        }])->get();
```

Comment: Will it give first row of each product_type ids?

Comment: yeah . 
App\Models\Category::with(['products'=>function($query){return $query->first();}])->get();

Comment: Hi, it gave 1st data only, all the other categories are empty.

Comment: I tested  , it gives for each category the first product , make sure ur database fillable with multidata (products and categories).